# Creating a scrollable tbody within a table with a new css of tbody

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, html-table, document-body

I have a working table with a scrolling tbody by using css with the following within it.

```css
tbody{
  overflow:auto;
}

thread > tr, tbody{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thread>
    <tr>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>SerialNm</td>
    </tr>
  </thread>
  
  <tbody style="height:50px">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table
```

I am happy with this.

However on other more complex tables I am having to use tbody for specific formatting to get the required affect.

The issue I have is that doing the CSS above applies to all my tables everywhere, and I only want it for the tbody within this specific table.

I know that this means I need to make a class, however I have tried this;

```
    .tbody-scroll, tbody{
  overflow:auto;
}

thread > tr, tbody-scroll{
  display:block;
}
```

and obviously assigned the tbody in the table to have a class="tbody-scroll", and it does not behave in the same way, it shows the entire table instead of preventing the overflow and going to a scrollbar.

How do I create another instance of tbody with all these settings in to allow scrolling without affecting the 'default' tbody settings?

Comment: Have you tried to give the specific table an id (e.g. id="specificTable") and then adjusted your css selectors accordingly to #specificTable .tbody-scroll, tbody{ overflow:auto;
} and #specificTable thread > tr, tbody-scroll{
  display:block;
} ?

Answer (score 1):

Just to show you the suggested solution, applied to your situation:

```css
#specificTable tbody{
  overflow:auto;
}

#specificTable thread > tr, tbody{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<p> Specific table example</p>
<table id="specificTable">
  <thread>
    <tr>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>SerialNm</td>
    </tr>
  </thread>
  
  <tbody style="height:50px">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p> Other table example</p>
<table id="otherTable">
  <thread>
    <tr>
      <td>Item</td>
      <td>SerialNm</td>
    </tr>
  </thread>
  
  <tbody style="height:50px">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>12345</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That works great, the only issue I have is that the actual application im after has dynamic ID's. This code is for a table within a table which stores serial numbers. The tables id is SerialNumbersTable_@i.toString() which changes the ID as the code loops during population. I have read there is something to do with using [id=^SerialNumbersTable] tbody ..... but this doesnt seem to work?

Comment: If you mean to select the table that 'start with' SerialNumbersTable, then I assume your syntax is wrong. Please check this link out for css selector 'starts with' : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp